# Iterating to create tabs with gt in quarto

Tags: tidyverse, gt, quarto

Something that is very handy is to iterate through a variable and then dynamically create tabs based on values of that variable (here `homeworld`). This works well with the `results: asis` chunk option. I can make that work but there is some strange interaction with the {gt} package whereby I can only make gt work with `purrr::walk` if I use `gt::as_raw_html`. However if I just produce a single table outside of `purrr::walk` I don't need `gt::as_raw_html`. Here is the error message I get {gt} does not work:

> Error running filter
> /Applications/quarto/share/filters/quarto-pre/quarto-pre.lua:
> ...lications/quarto/share/filters/quarto-pre/quarto-pre.lua:2410:
> attempt to concatenate a nil value (local 'v') stack traceback:
> ...lications/quarto/share/filters/quarto-pre/quarto-pre.lua:2417: in
> function
> <...lications/quarto/share/filters/quarto-pre/quarto-pre.lua:2415>

Here is the quarto (quarto version 1.1.175) code to reproduce:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
execute:
  warning: false
---

```{r r-pkgs}
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
library(gt)
library(purrr)

## just to simplify
starwars <- starwars %>% 
  filter(!is.na(sex))
```

# Does work

::: {.panel-tabset}

```{r}
#| results: asis

walk(
  unique(starwars$sex), \(hw) {
    cat(glue("## {hw} \n\n"))
    
    starwars %>% 
      filter(sex == hw) %>% 
      count(homeworld) %>% 
      head() %>% 
      gt() %>% 
      as_raw_html() %>% 
      print()
    
    cat("\n\n")
  }
)
```
:::


# Does not work

::: {.panel-tabset}

```{r}
#| results: asis
#| eval: false

walk(
  unique(starwars$sex), \(hw) {
    cat(glue("## {hw} \n\n"))
    
    starwars %>% 
      filter(sex == hw) %>% 
      count(homeworld) %>% 
      head() %>% 
      gt() %>% 
      print()
    
    cat("\n\n")
  }
)
```
:::

## single does work
```{r}
#| results: asis
starwars %>% 
  count(homeworld) %>% 
  head() %>% 
  gt()
```
````

Comment: your code works for me as intended with the quarto version is `‘1.0.38’` but then when upgraded to quarto version `‘1.1.189’` I get the same error. So I would suggest to create a issue [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posting back answer from the duplicate issue in [quarto-dev/quarto-cli#2370](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/2370)

## About the issue

The behavior you see has to do with the `print` method used, and the iteration with `walk()`

When you use `print()` after `gt()` or after `gt() %>% as_raw_html()` it will not have the same effect, as the `print` method used will not be the same. In the context of **knitr**, this matters.

Using `as_raw_html()` makes sense to include table as raw HTML in such document, and it probably will have the same result as when **gt** object are printing in knitting to HTML table (though the use of **htmltools**). When you use `gt() %>% print()`, it will not use the correct printing method that is used when just `gt()` is in a chunk (the `knit_print()` method [more on that here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/knit_print.html) for advanced understanding.

## More on how to create content dynamically with **knitr**

Let me add some context about **knitr** and dynamically created content.

Iterating to dynamically create content in **knitr** require to use the correct print method (usually `knit_print()`), and it is better to iterate on child content with `knitr::knit_child()` function that will correctly handle the printed output specific to sewing result in the document. We have some resource about that in R Markdown Cookbook that would apply to Quarto as well.

- About `knit_child()` : https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html
- About `knit_expand()` also : https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/knit-expand.html

As an example, this is how we recommend to dynamically create content when using **knitr** content so that R code result is correctly mixed with other content, specifically when the content to dynamically create is a mix of raw markdown, and R code results.

````markdown
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
execute:
  warning: false
keep-md: true
---

```{r r-pkgs}
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
library(gt)
library(purrr)

## just to simplify
starwars <- starwars %>% 
  filter(!is.na(sex))
```

# Tables

::: {.panel-tabset}

```{r}
#| output: asis
res <- purrr::map_chr(unique(starwars$sex), \(hw) {
    knitr::knit_child(text = c(
      "## `r hw`",
      "", 
      "```{r}",
      "#| echo: false",
      "starwars %>%",
      "  filter(sex == hw) %>%",
      "  count(homeworld) %>%",
      "  head() %>%",
      "  gt()",
      "```",
      "",
      ""
    ), envir = environment(), quiet = TRUE)
  })

cat(res, sep = '\n')
```
:::
````

You could also put the child content in a separate file for easier writing as in the Cookbook, by writing what you would need as document for one value you are iterating

````markdown
## `r hw`
 
```{r}
#| echo: false
starwars %>%
  filter(sex == hw) %>%
  count(homeworld) %>%
  head() %>%
  gt()
```
````

This is the safest way to mix markdown content (like `##`) with R code output ( like Tables or Htmlwidgets) which are content you can't easily just `cat()` into the file.

See more in the [issue](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/2370)

Comment: See also the `maketabs` function: https://hbiostat.org/rflow/rformat.html#quarto-report-writing-helper-functions